# jQuery Change anchor class and trigger click again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor when it's clicked it trigger a `click` function with ajax call. But when I click once and it changes is style the second `click` event is not triggered.

```
$(".makepartner").on('click', function (e) {
    $('span', this).removeClass('label-danger').addClass('label-success').html('Партньор');
    $.post('/ajax/partner', { 
        'type': 'makepartner', 
        'id': $(this).parent().find('input[name="id"]').val() 
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(".removepartner").on('click', function (e) {
    $('span', this).removeClass('label-success').addClass('label-danger').html('Не');
    $.post('/ajax/partner', { 
        'type': 'removepartner', 
        'id': $(this).parent().find('input[name="id"]').val() 
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<? if($hospital['paid'] > 0 ):?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$hospital['hospital_id'];?>" />
<a href='#' id='removepartner_<?=$hospital['id']?>' class='removepartner'>
    <span class="label label-sm label-success">Partner</span>
</a>
<? else: ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$hospital['hospital_id'];?>" />
<a href='#' id='makepartner_<?=$hospital['id']?>' class='makepartner'>
    <span class="label label-sm label-danger">Not a partner</span>
</a>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: whether the class `makepartner` and `removepartner` applied to the same element

Comment: I don't see any place in your code where you trigger clicks.

Comment: Is there anyway this could be done with one element?

Comment: You probably can. Use a variable or `.data()` value to record whether it should make or remove a partner, and toggle it every time they click.

Comment: We can make assumptions here, but it is better if you introduce some html

Comment: I have update the question with the HTML :)

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery expression like `$('.makepartner')` searches for DOM elements of class `'makepartner'` only once. If you add other elements with the same class to the document you need to re-evaluate it.

If you need to change anchor's class dynamically and still handle events, you can write something like this:

```
<div class="anchor-wrapper">
   <a class="makepartner">Anchor content</a>
</div>
```

and attach your handlers to `'.anchor-wrapper'`:

```
$('.anchor-wrapper').on('click', '.makepartner', function (e) {
    //do work...
});

$('.anchor-wrapper').on('click', '.removepartner', function (e) {
    //do work...
});
```

Comment: Did it this way, still no effect. Once clicked the anchor doesnt allow clicking again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 1 element using data-attributes http://jsfiddle.net/6fevy/

HTML

```
<a href='#' class='togglepartner' data-id="someid" data-type="removepartner">
    <span class="label label-sm label-success">Partner</span>
</a>
```

JS

```
$('.togglepartner').click(function(ev){
    var $this = $(this), 
        data = $this.data();
    $this.find('span')
         .toggleClass("label-success label-danger")
         .text({
             removepartner: 'Not partner',
             makepartner: 'Patner'
         }[data.type]).end()
         .data("type", {
             removepartner: 'makepartner', 
             makepartner: 'removepartner'}[data.type]);
    //send ajax;
    //$.post('/ajax/partner', data);

   ev.preventDefault(); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following script we can perfom it with a single function.

```
 $(document).on('click','.makepartner,.removepartner',comman_function);


 function comman_function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var anchorclass = $(this).attr('class');
     if(anchorclass == 'makepartner'){
        $('span', this).removeClass('label-danger').addClass('label-success').html('Партньор');
      }else{
        $('span', this).removeClass('label-success').addClass('label-danger').html('Не');
     }
     $.post('/ajax/partner', { 
        'type': anchorclass, 
        'id': $(this).parent().find('input[name="id"]').val() 
     },function(data){
      //ajax response data in return
     });

}
```